# Modifying controller data with AngularJS directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Directive Code**

```
app.directive('uiSwitch', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '_lib/custom/ui-switch/ui-switch-template.html', // markup for template
        scope: {
                info: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attrs){

            el.click(function(){
                // How do I change the controller data here?
            });

        }
    };
});
```

**Directive template code:**

```
<button class="switch-container" ng-click="info.callback()" ng-class="{off: info.off}">
        <div class="switch-inner">
        <div class="option option-on">{{info.labels[0]}}</div>
        <div class="switch"></div>
        <div class="option option-off">{{info.labels[1]}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
</button>
```

**How I call the directive from my controller's template:**

```
<ui-switch info="switch"></ui-switch>
```

**And the relevant code in my controller:**

```
    $scope.switch = {
        labels: ['Friend', 'Foe'],
        callback: function(){
            c('switch clicked')
        }
    }
```

I'd like to update some property on my controller when the switch gets clicked, eg. `$scope.switch.isOff = false`. However, I don't know how to update the controller's data from within the `link()` function of the directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `link` function has `scope` passed in as the first parameter of the function. If your data is on the same `scope`, access it via that:

```
link: function(scope, el, attrs){
    el.click(function(){
         scope.switch.isOff = false;
    })
}
```

It's important to note that `el.click` won't trigger a `$digest` cycle - so your data changes won't be reflected in the view until a cycle happens. You can force one with `$timeout` or a `$apply` (beware of the `$apply()` potential issues tho)

Comment: Thanks, including the tip on using $timeout to force the digest cycle.